# Mule could not resolve placeholder with maven exec

Tags: maven, mule

I'm using maven exec plugin to run Mule 3.  I have some properties that are correctly resolved when they are in my properties file, however if I try to provide them as a JVM option they do not get resolved/overridden.  Below is my maven exec config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-config</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app/prioritisation-api.xml</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/app</argument>
                    <argument>-Dmule3.http.root=http://localhost:8095</argument>
                </arguments>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I also tried using `-M-Dmule3.http.root=http://localhost:8095` but that did not work.

Comment: Does it work if you run the same from command line?

Comment: Is your Spring property placeholder configured to allow system properties overrides?

Answer (score 0):

The exec plugin has two goals `java` and `exec`. You are using the `java` which means:

(Excerpt from the docs):

> exec:java     Executes the supplied java class in the current VM with the
>   enclosing project's dependencies as classpath.

I would suggest to use the exec goals instead and start a separate JVM to which you can provided different parameters.